# How to write a simple lambda function to upload a pdf in Amazon S3?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda

I'm a new developer in node.js and I want to write a little lambda function (in node.js) that upload a pdf file (from the hard drive) to an Amazon S3 bucket.

Here is my code :

```
// dependencies
var util = require('util');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.handler = function (req, res) {
    var file = req.files.file;
    fs.readFile("‪C:\\Users\\zack\\Downloads\\test.pdf", function (err, data) {
        if (err) throw err; // Something went wrong!
        var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'myBucket3'}});
        s3bucket.createBucket(function () {
            var params = {
                Key: file.originalFilename, //file.name doesn't exist as a property
                Body: data
            };
            s3bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {
                // Whether there is an error or not, delete the temp file
                fs.unlink("‪C:\\Users\\zack\\Downloads\\test.pdf", function (err) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error(err);
                    }
                    console.log('Temp File Delete');
                });

                console.log("PRINT FILE:", file);
                if (err) {
                    console.log('ERROR MSG: ', err);
                    res.status(500).send(err);
                } else {
                    console.log('Successfully uploaded data');
                    res.status(200).end();
                }
            });
        });
    });
};
```

The lambda function shows me this error message :

```
 "errorMessage": "RequestId: 05024c81-f44b-11e6-a45e-57b13036ad96 Process exited before completing request"
```

And the cloudwatch :

```
START RequestId: e66a7653-f44b-11e6-8b1a-c511605a533b Version: $LATEST
2017-02-16T13:29:11.133Z    e66a7653-f44b-11e6-8b1a-c511605a533b    TypeError: Cannot read property 'file' of undefined
    at exports.handler (/var/task/invoices3/invoices3.js:17:25)
END RequestId: e66a7653-f44b-11e6-8b1a-c511605a533b
REPORT RequestId: e66a7653-f44b-11e6-8b1a-c511605a533b  Duration: 27.82 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 1024 MB    Max Memory Used: 23 MB  
RequestId: e66a7653-f44b-11e6-8b1a-c511605a533b Process exited before completing request
```

Can you tell me where is the problem please?? I'm not good at node.js at all.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 1):

> Process exited before completing request

You are getting this message because you are never notifying Lambda that the function has completed. You need to either call the `context.succeed()` function once you are done, or [update your code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-using-old-runtime.html#transition-to-new-nodejs-runtime) to use the newer `callback()` method, and call that when you are done.